# Codeigniter Error "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings" - Momentary malfunction

Tags: php, oracle, api, codeigniter

Our team maintains a PHP project written within CodeIgniter, and for about three years the project has been running successfully without errors.
The code interfaces with Oracle servers, so in the database.php file the value of $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8'; (MySql servers are not used at all).

Recently, multiple 'Unable to connect to your database server using the provided setting' errors began to be received following calls to some API in the php project from remote applications, with a reference to lines 338, 346 in the Loader.php file.

The interesting thing is that if such a call fails, and immediately after it a second call is made to the API with the same values, the operation ends successfully, that is, it is a momentary fault whose motive is not clear. In my analysis of the operation times, it was found that before each system failure the operation enters a timeout of one minute (exactly), crashes, and immediately after that the additional request succeeds.

I would appreciate it if someone could refer to further assistance.

Please note, I read online and looked for similar cases, but did not find any.
In all cases, it was about a permanent exception, that is, in every operation that is performed, the above error is received.
In the current case, the error occurs about 50 times an hour, while a minute after the process crashes and a second attempt is made to send the same information, the request goes through successfully.

Initially, I thought to check the possibility that the failures are caused by system/server overload/lack of resources.
I checked with our IT team, and they do not detect any abnormalities/problematic utilization of the CPU/RAM on the server.

Comment: My first thought was also a resource issue.  Are there any network problems?  Do you have any direct OCI8 or Oracle errors?  Are there any Oracle client log files?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherJones. I checked with our DBA guy and no anomalies or suspicious logs were found that could indicate a malfunction or the server being overloaded.

Comment: Are we talking about CI3 or CI4?

Comment: CI3 @KayAngevare

Comment: So if I read the file correct, you should have been seeing RuntimeExceptions regarding models and the locating of them?

Unable to locate the model you have specified: '.$model   |||||   $mod_path."models/".$path.$model.".php exists, but doesn't declare class ".$model

Comment: Negative, no errors of this type.